# Google visualization API - Stacked Bar Chart - Custom Tooltip

Tags: google-visualization

I've been trying to get a custom tooltip for a stacked bar chart.

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'Units');
data.addColumn('number', '1');
data.addColumn('number', '2');
data.addColumn('number', '3');
data.addColumn('number', '4');

_1 = 0.123
_2 = 0.23
_3 = 0.3
_4 = 0

data.addRow([_units, _1, _2, _3, _4,]);

var options = {
        isStacked: true,
        height: 150,
        chartArea: { height: 50 },
        legend: { position: 'top' },
};

bchart = new google.visualization.BarChart(bcontainer);
bchart.draw(data, options);
```

My question then is how to create a tooltip for each: _1, _2, _3, _4?

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is covered in the Google Documentation under [DataTable Roles](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles#tooltiprole)

In the Bar Chart documentation, it explains which roles are available for that chart [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart#Data_Format)

What you need to do is add additional columns to your data with the {role: tooltip} added, with that column showing what you want the tooltip to say.

For instance:

```
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Year');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Sales');
  data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'});
  data.addColumn('number', 'Expenses');
  data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'});
  data.addRows([
    ['2004', 1000, '1M$ sales in 2004', 400,  '$0.4M expenses in 2004'],
    ['2005', 1170, '1.17M$ sales in 2005', 460, '$0.46M expenses in 2005'],
    ['2006', 660,  '.66$ sales in 2006', 1120, '$1.12M expenses in 2006'],
    ['2007', 1030, '1.03M$ sales in 2007', 540, '$0.54M expenses in 2007']
  ]);
```

The final code will look like this:

```
function drawVisualization() {
  // Create and populate the data table.
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Year');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Sales');
  data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'});
  data.addColumn('number', 'Expenses');
  data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'});
  data.addRows([
    ['2004', 1000, '1M$ sales in 2004', 400,  '$0.4M expenses in 2004'],
    ['2005', 1170, '1.17M$ sales in 2005', 460, '$0.46M expenses in 2005'],
    ['2006', 660,  '.66$ sales in 2006', 1120, '$1.12M expenses in 2006'],
    ['2007', 1030, '1.03M$ sales in 2007', 540, '$0.54M expenses in 2007']
  ]);

  // Create and draw the visualization.
  new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
      draw(data,
           {title:"Yearly Coffee Consumption by Country",
            isStacked: true,
            width:600, height:400,
            vAxis: {title: "Year"},
            hAxis: {title: "Sales"}}
      );
}
```

See an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/N6yhZ/1/).

Comment: I spent hours on this yesterday trying to figure this out. Thank you very much.